# wp - C#; string length property is not works?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Why string length property is not working in C# while developing app for Windows Phone. here's my code;

```
    private void showName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "UserName";
        MessageBox.Show(name.Length);
    }
```

Error

```
'System.Windows.Controls.Page' does not contain a definition for 'Length'
```

Comment: @KevinDeVoe Are you serious?

Comment: @KevinDeVoe it's a property not a function call.

Comment: You can receive the error you get if Length is not spelled right or is in the wrong casing.

Comment: @user2655873 The below answers are correct. If they don't work then you have an error somewhere else on your page.

Comment: Below answerns have nothing to do with the Problem. If he cannot even find the definition 'Length', then surely he will never find it's method

Comment: @all:   
it works. i did mistake. thank u all

Comment: @Daniel The below answers corrected his error, just gave him a new one.

Comment: They could never correct the error 'definition not found', only 'The best overloaded method...has some invalid arguments' or 'cannot convert int to string'. He surely named the string same way as another object

Comment: @Daniel Agreed but the implementation of name.Length would have never worked for a Messagebox. In the end he would need to convert it to a string anyway.

Comment: Surely it would have never worked because it convert an integer into an string. But that was not the error and neither it helped him. The comments maybe helped, but surely not the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sent a string to the MessageBox. `Length` outputs an integer

Convert the `name.Length`. Both of the below ideas will work.

```
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(str.Length));
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show(str.Length.ToString());
```

**EDIT** - In response to OPs comment.
You can also receive the error you get if you have .Length spelled wrong or cased wrong.

`MessageBox.Show(str.length);` will show your error. (Capitolize the "l")

Comment: @Mayank. You probally can.

Comment: Error : `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: you most certainly can!

Comment: if you have length spelled wrong or cased wrong you can receive that error. Check you are actually calling the method.

Comment: @user2655873 Please post your exact code. There's no way the code you provided could raise a `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Length'` error

Comment: Lol @ downvotes for everyone..We fixed his first error..This is a new one he is receiving...

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be converted to a String!

```
MessageBox.Show(name.Length.ToString());
```

Comment: Error : `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Do you have an object named `name` in your class?

Comment: Rename the string and try again

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [MSDN page for MessageBOx Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.messagebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), 
You can read the parameter of the 'MessageBox.Show()' is a string.

And if you read the [MSDNpage of the string.Length proprety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you know this return an integer.

You can resolve your problem if you convert your integer to string with :

```
string myMessage = myString.Length.ToString(); // Convert my Integer to String.
```

or

```
string myMessage = Convert.ToString(myString.Length); // Convert my Integer to String
```

and finaly :

```
MessageBox.Show(myMessage); // Show my string.
```